# Irrationality of $\frac {\log_{10}m}{\log_{10}n}$

Tags: calculus

I was working on a question which states that

Prove that $\frac {\log_{10}m}{\log_{10}n}$ is an irrational number if $m$ and $n$ are co-primes.

I tackled it in this way:

Let  $\frac{\log_{10}m}{\log_{10}n}$ is a rational number.

So $\frac{\log_{10}m}{\log_{10}n}$=${\frac{p}{q}}$
since $(m,n)=1 \implies \log_{10}m=p $ and $\log_{10} n=q$.

So $m=10^p$ and $n=10^q$.
Hence $(m,n)=10$ which is a contradiction.

So our assumption was wrong and $\frac {log_{10}m}{log_{10}n}$ is an irrational number.

Is it right? Please suggest me another way to do it....

Comment: No....the fact that $\frac ab=\frac cd$ does not imply that $a=c,b=d$.  $\frac {\pi}{2\pi}=\frac 12$, say.

Comment: I said ($a,b)$=1

Comment: You mean $(m,n)$?  But you haven't proven that $(m,n)=1\implies \log_{10}m=p$ or anything like that.

Comment: $\log_{10} m$ and $\log_{10} n$ will most likely be irrational.

Comment: ohh that's my fault because I am knew for mathjax

Comment: $p$ and $q$ are irrational unless $m$ or $n$ is equal to $10^K$  for some  non-negative integer $K.$ And you should not write $(\log m)/\log n=p/q\implies \log m= p\land  log n=q$. Rather, "Let $p=\log m"$. etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\frac{log(m)}{log(n)}$=$\frac{a}{b}$

So, $b\times{log(m)}=a\times{log(b)}$

$log(m^b)=log(n^a)$

$m^b=n^a$

Which is contradiction as m,n are coprime.

Answer (score 5):

By the change of basis formula your expression is $$\log_nm$$

If that is rational, say it equals $\frac ab$ for $a,b\in \mathbb Z$, then we have $n^a=m^b$ from which your claim becomes obvious.